# How to click an element and move it to another element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a chess game in React with just the bishop and knight pieces. I'm stuck trying to figure out how to detect when a piece is clicked and how to move the piece from one square to the square I choose. Do I need to use event.target to accomplish this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class Chessboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      knightSelected: false,
      bishopSelected: false

    }
    this.knightMoveHandler = this.knightMoveHandler.bind(this);
  }

  knightMoveHandler(e) {

    this.setState({
      knightSelected: true
    });
    console.log(this.state.knightSelected);
  }

  bishopMoveHandler(e) {

    this.setState({

      bishopSelected: true
    });
    console.log(this.state.knightSelected);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <table>
          <tbody className="chessboard">
            <tr className="row">
              <td className="square">1</td>
              <td className="square">2</td>
              <td className="square">3</td>
              <td className="square">4</td>
              <td className="square">5</td>
              <td className="square">6</td>
              <td className="square">7</td>
              <td className="square">8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr className="row">
              <td className="square">9</td>
              <td className="square">10</td>
              <td className="square">11</td>
              <td className="square">12</td>
              <td className="square">13</td>
              <td className="square">14</td>
              <td className="square">15</td>
              <td className="square">16</td>
            </tr>
            <tr className="row">
              <td className="square">17</td>
              <td className="square">18</td>
              <td className="square">19</td>
              <td className="square">20</td>
              <td className="square">21</td>
              <td className="square">22</td>
              <td className="square">23</td>
              <td className="square">24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr className="row">
              <td className="square">25</td>
              <td className="square">26</td>
              <td className="square">27</td>
              <td className="square">28</td>
              <td className="square">29</td>
              <td className="square">30</td>
              <td className="square">31</td>
              <td className="square">32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr className="row">
              <td className="square">33</td>
              <td className="square">34</td>
              <td className="square">35</td>
              <td className="square">36
                <span className="knight" value="1" onClick={this.knightMoveHandler}>&#9822;</span>
              </td>
              <td className="square" >37
                <span className="bishop" onClick={this.bishopMoveHandler}>&#9821;</span>
              </td>
              <td className="square">38</td>
              <td className="square">39</td>
              <td className="square">40</td>
            </tr>
            <tr className="row">
              <td className="square">41</td>
              <td className="square">42</td>
              <td className="square">43</td>
              <td className="square">44</td>
              <td className="square">45</td>
              <td className="square">46</td>
              <td className="square">47</td>
              <td className="square">48</td>
            </tr>
            <tr className="row">
              <td className="square">49</td>
              <td className="square">50</td>
              <td className="square">51</td>
              <td className="square">52</td>
              <td className="square">53</td>
              <td className="square">54</td>
              <td className="square">55</td>
              <td className="square">56</td>
            </tr>
            <tr className="row">
              <td className="square">57</td>
              <td className="square">58</td>
              <td className="square">59</td>
              <td className="square">60</td>
              <td className="square">61</td>
              <td className="square">62</td>
              <td className="square">63</td>
              <td className="square">64</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Chessboard;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) might help you here.

To select a Bishop or Knight:
Apply the onClick event listener to `.chessboard`. Then check if the element clicked is actually the expected element.

```html
<tbody className="chessboard" onClick={this.clickHandler}>
```

```js
this.clickHandler = e => {
  if(e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('square')){
    // do stuff here
  }
}
```

To check if a square is empty or filled:

```js
this.state = {
  isFilledWith: 'empty' or 'bishop' or 'knight'
}
```

Now when you want to move a Bishop/Knight, you have to figure out the possible places where they can move, maybe make an array out of it. When it's actually moved, call a function that changes the isFilledWith state for that square.